# Stop execute previous javascript in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

If I click on button javascript will be append to iframe.

example:

```
<button id="run">Click me!</button>
<textarea></textarea>

var iframe = here_is_iframe_object;

$('#run").click(function(e) {
    $(iframe).find("script[id=myScript]").remove();
    $(iframe).append("<script id='myScript'>"+ $("textarea").val() +"</script>");
});
```

If I put into the textarea setInterval with alert for example and after that put simple alert, it will be execute setInterval with alert and new alert at the same time.

```
setInterval(function() {
    alert(true);
}, 5000);
```

How to stop previous javascript and execute only new code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Somehow this problem seems a bit backwards to me. Is the content of the iframe on the same domain as the rest and under your control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we do need a little more info about your code (ie context).
For what I understood, this snippet works as expected (when typos are corrected)
But be carefull, I'm no specialist but I think that you're in the case eval() can be dangerous : [Look at this answer about using eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1651146/3702797).

To stop a `setInterval()` timer, use `clearInterval()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval)