# Execute a function from object value in javascript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to execute a function from each object key here is the code.

```js
var testObj = { text: "this is text" , alltext: "this is all text" };

function text() {
    alert("this is test function for first value");
}

function alltext() {
    alert("this is test function for first second!");
}

for (item in testObj) { 
    console.log(item);
    item();
}
```

This gives me that `item` not a function.

Please visit this link to see the original code. I am using Backbone.js to create a form.The code is commented.

http://vianx.com/tst/script2.js

in this case gives that the "fieldConstructor" in not a function.

Comment: Well, `item()` isn't a function.

Comment: Only solution in your case, without assigning those functions as members of an object... is `eval`.

Comment: You could grab the field, and use [eval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) to call a function.

Comment: Put your funcs in an object like `var funcs = {text:function(){},alltext:function(){}};` then do `funcs[item]()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I believe you are mistaken about how a dictionary works in javascript. The first value is a key and will always be a string value to do what you want you can do this

```js
var testObj = [[text, "this is text"] , [alltext, " thi is all text" ]];

function text () {
  alert( "this is test function for first value");
}

function alltext () {
  alert( "this is test function for first second!" );
}


for ( index in testObj ) {
   
  console.log(index);
  testObj[index][0]();
}
```

Comment: I have used the underscore "pair" object method to convert the object into array "key,value" pairs.Then  I can execute them.

_.pairs({one: 1, two: 2, three: 3});
=> [["one", 1], ["two", 2], ["three", 3]]

Comment: @Jack Mata, please do not indent the tags for code snippets (just the tags). it makes funny renderings.

Answer (score 0):

You should use JavaScript [`eval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) function:

```
for (item in testObj) {
    console.log(testObj[item]);
    eval(item + "()");
}
```

Comment: Is there is anyway to avoid eval ?? Because it has a security risk?

Comment: It depends… A malicious user is potentially able to execute any client-side script he wants with his browser's *Developer Tools*. Remember that these scripts will be running on *his* client, *not* on your server. To learn more, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651118/security-risks-of-using-eval-to-execute-user-input-in-javascript

Comment: @codeforce It's only a security risk if the contents of `testObj` can be manipulated outside the control of the user.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could reference the functions from within your object

```
var testObj = { text: text , alltext : alltext };

function text() {
  alert( "this is test function for first value");
}

function alltext() {
  alert( "this is test function for first second!" );
}


for ( item in testObj ) {

  console.log(item);
  testObj[item]();
}
```

Comment: I can not because I have a data from outside source as key value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Construct testObj is like this:

```
var testObj = { 
    text: function(){alert("this is test function for first value")} ,
    alltext : function(){alert("this is test function for first second!")} 
};
```

Then simply call `testObj.a();`

Comment: You mean `testObj[item]`. You have to use `[]` notation to access an object property dynamically.

Comment: No, that will look for a property literally named `item`, not use the value of the `item` variable.

Comment: I would argue. They are quite the same, except that the square bracket operator can access object's members using a string variable, whereas dot operator can only use literals. Please, take a look at: [/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets](/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying. `testObj.a()` looks for a literal property named `a`, it doesn't use the value of the variable `a`. If the property name is in a string variable, you have to use square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by attaching the dynamic functions to the window object.

```
var testObj = { text: "this is text", alltext: " thi is all text" };

for (var item in testObj) {
    window[item] = function () {alert("hello world")};
}

console.log(window['text'],window['alltext']);

window.text();
window.alltext();
```

The functions can also be called without using "window." i.e.:

```
text();
alltext();
```

Or if you are wanting to call a function by property name dynamically...

```
var testObj = { text: "this is text", alltext: " thi is all text" };

window['text'] = function() {
    alert("this is test function for first value");
}

window['alltext']  = function (){
    alert("this is test function for first second!");
}

for (var item in testObj) {
    window[item]();// = function () {alert("hello world")};
}
```