# Clojure: Name of variables in a list

Tags: clojure

I have a something like this:

```
(def a "text")
(def b "text")
(def c nil)
(def d 8)
(def e "")

(def testlist (list a b c d e ))
```

Now, is there any way to get the string of the variable names? I assume a 'no' is the most likely answer.

[name](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/name) does not seem to work, as it only returns the value. Does the list only contain the values after def?

EDIT: What i forgot and that may be essential to this question: i can neither use eval nor can i use defmacro, both are not allowed (for safety etc. reasons). So, yeah...

Comment: This is a guess: I don't know clojure. But I suspect you're creating the list by value, so the list contains only the values, not references to the variables.

Comment: You can construct a list of symbols: `(list 'a 'b 'c 'd 'e)` or vars: `(list #'a #'b #'c #'d #'e)`.

Comment: You really need a macro to do this, and usually when people want to do this, the reason is not very compelling and almost always not a good idea.

Comment: @Josh the reason is, i want to check for nil and empty and then ouput the names of those variables. Idea is that i dont know how many elements are in this list, just that every element gets checked a result gets returned.

Comment: Could you use a map, `{ "a" a "b" b "c" c "d" d "e" e}`? That way you get the name and value...

Comment: @Kris Yes i can, i was just searching for a lazy way to not do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use macro to do this (just for fun. i don't think it is a viable usecase at all)

```
user> (defmacro list+ [& syms]
        `(with-meta (list ~@syms) {:vars (quote ~syms)}))
#'user/list+

user> (def testlist (list+ a b c d e))
#'user/testlist

user> (-> testlist meta :vars)
(a b c d e)

user> (defn nil-vals-names [data]
        (for [[v name] (map vector data (-> data meta :vars))
              :when (nil? v)]
          name))
#'user/nil-vals-names

user> (nil-vals-names testlist)
(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to get a string from the variable names since Clojure will evaluate them as soon as possible to produce the `testlist`

```
=> (def testlist (a b c d e ))
("text" "text" nil 8 "")
```

However, you can [quote the list](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/quote) to retrieve the symbol associated to each variable name

```
=> (def testlist (quote (a b c d e ))) ;; equivalent to '(a b c d e ))
(a b c d e)
```

And then transform these symbols into strings with the `str` function

```
=> (map str testlist)
("a" "b" "c" "d" "e")
```

Later, you can `eval` this list to retrieve the value in the context of your namespace

```
=> (map eval testlist)
("text" "text" nil 8 "")
```

Note that using `eval` with an external input (e.g. `read-line`) can create [a security risk in Clojure and other languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651118/security-risks-of-using-eval-to-execute-user-input-in-javascript).

Moreover, the list has to be evaluated in the same namespace as its definition. Otherwise, Clojure will not be able to resolve the symbols.

```
=> (ns otherns)
=> (map eval user/testlist)
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: a in this context
```

The best practice in most case would be to use [macros](https://www.braveclojure.com/writing-macros/)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite unclear what are you trying to achieve, bit still there is a possible way.

`meta` function take a reference and returns a map with `:name` field that holds a sting with the variable name:

```
user=> (def foo 42)
#'user/foo

user=> (meta #'foo)
{:line 1, :column 1, 
 :file "/some/tmp/file.clj", 
 :name foo, 
 :ns #namespace[user]}
```